# Pandas cut method excludes lower bound

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to bin a dataframe column that contains ages in the range 0 to 100.
When I try and use a bin to include the zero ages it does not work.

Here is an demo using a list with the range of my data:

```
pd.cut(pd.Series(range(101)), [0, 24, 49, 74, 100])
```

The zero value in the range returns NaN from the cut.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IIUC you need to set `include_lowest` argument to `True`. From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

> **include_lowest** : *bool*
>     Whether the first interval should be left-inclusive or not.

For your case:

```
pd.cut(pd.Series(range(101)), [0,24,49,74,100], include_lowest=True)

In [148]: pd.cut(pd.Series(range(101)), [0,24,49,74,100], include_lowest=True).head(10)
Out[148]:
0    [0, 24]
1    [0, 24]
2    [0, 24]
3    [0, 24]
4    [0, 24]
5    [0, 24]
6    [0, 24]
7    [0, 24]
8    [0, 24]
9    [0, 24]
dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [[0, 24] < (24, 49] < (49, 74] < (74, 100]]
```

Comment: I really should have read the docs on that one. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Why is `include_lowest=True` not the default value?

Comment: I was looking for this as well. I saw the `right` argument and looked for `left` but missed `include_lowest`.